# Ursina popup window crashes immediatly after running the app

Tags: python-3.x, debian, ursina

I'm trying to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHSRaVeQxIk to get to know Ursina.

This is my code:

```
from ursina import *
        
app = Ursina()

test_square = Entity(model = 'circle', color = color.red)

app.run
```

The app window opens but closes immediately.
This is the message I get in Visual Studio:

In Wayland:

```
/usr/bin/env /home/sersys/python/environments/firsttry/bin/python /home/sersys/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.12.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 50081 -- /home/sersys/python/environments/firsttry/Projects/Project1/firstproject.py
package_folder: /home/sersys/python/environments/firsttry/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ursina
asset_folder: /home/sersys/python/environments/firsttry/Projects/Project1
Known pipe types:
  glxGraphicsPipe
(4 aux display modules not yet loaded.)
Xlib:  extension "XFree86-DGA" missing on display ":1".
:pnmimage:png(warning): iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

in X11:

```
/usr/bin/env /home/sersys/python/environments/firsttry/bin/python /home/sersys/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.12.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 53191 -- /home/sersys/python/environments/firsttry/Projects/Project1/firstproject.py
package_folder: /home/sersys/python/environments/firsttry/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ursina
asset_folder: /home/sersys/python/environments/firsttry/Projects/Project1
Known pipe types:
  glxGraphicsPipe
(4 aux display modules not yet loaded.)
:pnmimage:png(warning): iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

Xlib is installed according to pip install. I can't decipher what the rest means. According to some forums `known incorrect sRGB profile` is just a warning and not an error.

Specs:

```
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 12
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.103.0
Qt Version: 5.15.8
Kernel Version: 6.1.0-10-amd64 (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland
Processors: 24 × AMD Ryzen 9 7900X 12-Core Processor
Memory: 61.9 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: AMD Radeon Graphics
Manufacturer: ASUS
Python 3.11.2
```

I would like to know if the app is crashing (permission issues, python not installed properly, not using the virtual environment correctly?) or Ursina can't render a window (because of a missing package, misconfiguration?) and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `app.run()`, not `app.run`.

Comment: Ok, that works but the error messages still appear. Is '4 aux display modules not yet loaded' something I should be concerned about?